# In Ruby on Rails, is copying vendor/gems/somegem from one project to another project the same as freezing the gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I was told that copying from

```
vendor/gems/somegem
```

from proj1 to proj2's folder will essentially freeze the gem into the project.  The gem `somegem` is an internal gem, so there is no repository to install it from.  But I wonder how will it work with Rails 3, since we need to use

```
gem 'somegem'
```

in the Gemfile, and supposedly when we do a `gem list`, the name of the gem should show up.  What is a good / proper way to do this?  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `Gemfile.lock` file stores the versions of the gems in use, along with any and all dependencies, so you can essentially copy over your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile you can tell bundler to get the gem from a local path:

```
gem 'somegem', :path => "some_path/to/somegem"
```

If your 'gem' is in fact a plugin then just copy the files to `vendor/plugins`.

If install.rb in the plugin directory does anything special you may want to run this manually.

Comment: so I think in this case, it is `gem 'somegem', :path => "vendor/gems/somegem"` ?

Comment: but it looks like Rails 3's bundle install needs a .gemspec to do bundle install... so my coworker put them in the `vendor/plugins` folder instead... what's the difference for gems vs plugins i wonder...

Comment: A gem is effectively a packaged ruby application according to the Rubygems spec. A plugin is a packaged ruby application that extends the core rails framework. Update my answer.

Comment: In Rails 2.2, it was in `vendor/gems`, and in Rails 3, now we have it in `vendor/plugins`... I think sooner or later I will look more into the mechanism of the `vendor` folder...