# how to copy pods from one xcode project to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I usually use the same pods for multiple projects, however I find myself having to run `pod install` each time. Isn't there a way to reuse existing pods for every new project?

I know in rails [the way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380818/766570) is by copying Gemfile.lock and then running `bundle install` and that would avoid having to download all the gems (ie packages/libraries) from their respective repos.. further, Podfile.lock is pretty much coacoa pod's counterpart to Gemlock.file (ie [it keeps track](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) of the specific pod versions that got copied over). I'm guessing there must be a way to transfer specific pods from one project to another similar to how it's done on rails.

Comment: You are wrong about what Gemfile.lock does. It only holds exact version of a gem, which doesn't have to be specified in Gemfile. Gem file are stored in another dir, so copying just Gemfile.lock gives you nothing. Removed RoR tag.